How do Trinitarians defend the unfalsifiability of the Trinity?
Background:
Christian Trinitarians believe "that there is one eternal being of God – indivisible, infinite. This one being of God is shared by three co-equal, co-eternal persons, the Father, the Son, and the Spirit". Trinitarians generally believe that this doctrine is taught in the New Testament. They also generally believe the trinity is (minimally) simply compatible with the Hebrew bible, or (maximally) also clearly taught in the Hebrew bible. This is in contrast with traditional Jewish belief in a unitary deity.
The authors of the Hebrew bible make several statements about the oneness of G-d:

Deuteronomy 6:4 - "Hear, O Israel: The Lord our G-d, the Lord is one."


Isaiah 44:6 - "Thus says the Lord, the King of Israel and his Redeemer, the Lord of hosts: 'I am the first and I am the last; besides me there is no god.'"


Deuteronomy 4:35 - "To you it was shown, that you might know that the Lord is G-d; there is no other besides Him."

These authors do not write about distinctions between being and personhood.
Unfalsifiable belief?
Under trinitarian hermeneutical approaches, the above verses are not contrary to the trinity because they could be interpreted to refer to the single being of G-d, and not to the trinitarian multiplicity of persons. This is a curious interpretation since concepts of distinction between “person” and “being” only appear in literature which post-date the completion of the Hebrew bible.
Question
If seemingly clear verses attesting to ontological oneness can be used in support of trinitarian doctrine, what could a biblical author have written in the Hebrew bible that would falsify the trinity? Is the trinity only falsifiable with a verse such as "There is only one person of G-d", "G-d is only one being and one person", or even "The trinity as defined by Christian patristic fathers and ecumenical councils in the 4th Century CE is false"?

Of course you cannot falsify the Trinitarian doctrine by citing the ontological oneness go God because Trinitarian theology intrinsically acknowledges the oneness. That is, Trinitarian theology is not tritheism.

@eques you're just repeating my point about trinitarian interpretations of the verses I cited. The question is what could possibly falsify the triune claim? There are no discussions of "being" vs "person" to be found in the Hebrew bible, so is the only possible dispositive statement "The trinity as defined by Christian patristic fathers and ecumenical councils is false"?

It could only be falsifiable with verses that could only be interpreted as excluding 3 persons in God or that one of the specific persons isn't God.

@eques so the Hebrew bible would have had to enumerate all of the persons who are not God ahead of time?

Not what I said. Either three-ness would have to be excluded entirely or a particular person would have to be excluded as divine. In other words, Trinitarian theology is broadly 3 concepts: Oneness of God, 3 persons, the particular persons (Father, Son and Holy Spirit). We established you can't base a fallibility claim on the first concept.

I've very confused by the use of old testament "We have one God, everyone else has false polythesim!" verses. These verses directly oppose the surrounding paganism of baal, etc...  Also, the Trinity is strictly a new testament thing right?

if Jesus == God and Holy Spirit == God and The Father == God, then why is The Father greater than all of them? The Father is greater than I, If all beings you mentioned are is God then they should be equal in terms of authority but apparently The Father is supreme to all the others which falsifies that doctrine

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Great question. It's also not particular relevant here and almost certainly answered elsewhere on this site.

I will mark the first answer as accepted that provides a statement the Hebrew bible could have made that would have falsified the trinity

I don't think the doctrine is falsifiable, and I don't think it needs  to be. Falsifiability is a standard for scientific hypotheses, not truth claims generally. A statement may be true or false regardless of its falsifiability. We can examine something mundane to see that this is true. Is the statement "2+2=4" falsifiable? No, on the contrary, it's self-evident. What about syllogisms? "All men are mortal. Socrates is a man. Socrates is mortal." This isn't falsifiable. The conclusion follows naturally from the premises. The Trinity is an axiom of theology, not a scientific hypothesis.

This might be a good question, but it is clearly a philosophical one, not a theological one.   If I didn't close it as philosophical, I would have closed it as inviting answers from too many perspectives. If you want to add "How do Trinitarians defend the falsifiability of their belief" or something awkward like that, I think it would be OK, but we're not going to police the inevitable anti-Trinitarian perspectives that will come out to answer this question when it clearly invites them.

@PeterTurner that’s disappointing. This is a philosophy of theology question, as is this https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/102181/how-can-the-christian-faith-be-reconciled-with-the-epicurean-problem-of-evil or this https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/101012/how-can-we-infallibly-know-that-the-catholic-church-is-infallible

@avi the second one is a question about Catholicism, the first one I think should be closed.  But I'm not going to mod-hammer close it, if I see a few community members VTC, I would though

@PeterTurner I've edited this question

@AviAvraham "This is a philosophy of theology question" Yes, I agree, and if you notice that those kinds of questions need more defending to stay open it's more of a reflection of some Protestant denominations' distrust of the application of Greek philosophy (or now I should say, Chinese philosophy) to Christian theology.  It's good this Q remains open, but to get the community blessing next time, I would cite a Christian Meta Q that has decided that philosophical theology is "on topic".  If there's not one, I would start one there to create a precedent.

A key aspect of the Trinity is that Jesus (that is, the Son) is God. If it could be clearly shown that Jesus is not God (as many non-Trinitarians attempt to do), that would disprove Trinitarianism. Thus, the debate focuses mainly on those verses that seem to prove this, as weighed against those verses that seem to prove that Jesus is God.

In a comment, you ask for "a statement the Hebrew bible could have made that would have falsified the trinity". (I'm guessing you mean to single out what we would call 'the Old Testament', as opposed to both Testaments?) To that end, I suppose something like "the one called the Son of God is not God" would suffice. Since we find Messianic prophesies there, Isaiah seems like a good place for such a statement... but what we actually find is that "His name shall be called [...] Mighty God". It's much more likely that any such statements would be found in the New Testament, and especially one might expect the Apostles (i.e. in the Epistles) to say something if e.g. Thomas' confession in John 20:28 shouldn't be taken as indicating Jesus' divinity, or if Jesus and the Father are separate. Again, however, we find sayings such as "there is [...] one God and Father of all" (Ephesians 4:4-6) and "our God and Savior Jesus Christ" (2 Peter 1:1).
On the other hand, you have many passages that do seem to speak of the Father and Son as distinct (examples). These do indicate a difference between the Father and the Son... but Trinitarianism affirms that difference. Again, what is needed is Scripture that clearly shows that the Father and the Son are wholly distinct, or that Jesus is wholly not God / not Divine.

Thanks for the thoughtful answer. I made an edit to the original question to be clearer

Then there's the binitarian view, where both Father and Son are God, but don't have a two-in-one mystery relationship. The issue then is whether God's holy spirit is an immaterial substance or a Person.

@RayButterworth, if they're both God, and there is one God, how would they not have some sort of two-in-one relation?

@Matthew, in the quoted scriptures, "Lord" is "YHWH", so it says "YHWH" is one, not "God" is one. If YHWH is the pre-incarnate Son, and no one knew the Father existed until Jesus revealed him ("no man knoweth the Son, but the Father; neither knoweth any man the Father, save the Son, and he to whomsoever the Son will reveal him."), as far as the Israelites were concerned their only god was YHWH (later known as the Son). ¶ Compare with Frank and Joe Hardy: There is only one Frank, but both Frank and Joe are Hardy.

@Matthew, by "two-in-one relation" I mean the mystery relationship ("which can be expressed by the finite mind only in terms of analogy, e.g., the Trinity" — Catholic Encyclopedia) where there are three distinct persons that are in some mystical way all the same being.

Let me add my two cents by adding a Thomistic perspective to the discussion.
There are two classes of truths: truths of reason and truths of faith. Truths of reason are those that can be known by the natural light of human reason and truths of faith are those that require divine revelation to be known.
That God exists is a truth of reason[1], meaning that no revelation is needed to know that God exists (how that demonstration is done is another topic[2]). However, the Trinity is a truth of faith, meaning that no person can claim to have come to that knowledge by reason alone. In other words, we cannot know that God is a Trinity unless God reveals it.
Truths of reason part from basic principles that are self-evident and cannot be denied without falling into contradiction[3], such as the principle of non-contradiction. Together with our senses, reason allows us to compose and divide concepts, to infer conclusions from premises, and to judge the truth of propositions. This means that truths of reason can be falsified, in the sense that they can be shown to be false by means of a contradiction.
Truths of faith, on the other hand, are not falsifiable in that sense. You either believe them or you don't. Another thing would be to ask whether the Trinity is a coherent concept. That is, whether the concept of the Trinity is logically consistent. This is a different question and one that can be answered by reason, i.e., by analyzing the concept of the Trinity and seeing if it leads to contradictions.
Thus, the concept of Trinity can be said falsifiable only in the sense that if you can prove that the concept of the Trinity is logically inconsistent, then you can say that the Trinity is false. This is because, according to Aquinas, there's no such thing as a double truth: something cannot be true in faith and false in reason[4].
Now, those who believe in the Trinity will support their belief by providing a particular interpretation of the Scriptures and those who don't will provide a different interpretation. Because there is no agreed-upon authority between the two groups, the premises from which they start are different and, therefore, the debate about whether the concept is coherent or not will be fruitless.
References:
[1] Summa Theologiae, I, q. 2, a. 2
[2] ibidem, a. 3
[3] De Veritate, q. 1, a. 1, co.
[4] STh, I, q. 1, a. 8

Welcome to the site, Nacib. That was a well-thought out and interesting answer. Although this question has been closed, don't let that put you off answering again!

Indeed, the two Deuteronomy and one Isaiah texts quoted do not contradict the Trinity doctrine: there is only one God. All other so-called gods are false gods, would-be-gods, or man-made imaginary gods. Nor is there anything already written in the Hebrew scriptures that falsifies the Trinity doctrine. It is a bit pointless asking what could any writer of those scriptures have written to falsify it, for that's not going to happen. The Hebrew scriptures are complete, and Christians have based all their belief in God, Christ, and the Holy Spirit upon those ancient scriptures. They quote frequently from them to substantiate their evaluation of Jesus as the Christ, the Son of God. Of course, different interpretations of the Hebrew prophet's words gives rise to different views of Christ. For instance, some would disagree that Isaiah (in 9:6) foretold Messiah to have the titles of Mighty God and Everlasting Father. But that brings us into the realms of interpretation, not reasons to falsify any belief.
Phrases about the 'person' and 'being' of God, including points made in ecumenical councils, could not possibly have been written into the Hebrew scriptures, for all of those only arose centuries after the Hebrew canon was closed. No, the only way the Trinity doctrine could be falsified is to take the doctrine and show from both Hebrew and Greek scriptures that it is contrary to the clear teaching of the whole Bible. Many people say that is exactly the case, and so they reject the Trinity doctrine, even groups that would be considered Christian. They have put forth their arguments, often clouded by interpretations or subtly changed renditions of Bible texts, but when trinitarians suggest that, they bat the ball right back into their court, saying trinitarians have clouded the issue with their interpretations and by sticking to ancient translations of the scriptures. So the arguments keep going round in circles.
There are, however, other ways to falsify the Trinity doctrine. If it could be proved that no God existed; or that Jesus of Nazareth never existed, or that (if he did exist) was never resurrected from the dead and be seen to ascend bodily into heaven... such things would silence all Trinitarians (and many others, besides.)
Yet the Greek scriptures explain exactly what the difficulty is, with regards to their claims about the person of Jesus Christ being God, yet that not violating the scriptural Hebrew truth that there is only one true God. An ardent Jewish scholar of the Hebrew scriptures, who once persecuted Christians, encountered the resurrected, glorified Christ and became a Christian. He wrote a lot about this Jesus, expounding relevant Hebrew texts along the way. For example, after detailing Christ as the one by whom all things were created in heaven and on earth, being the express image of God, who through the body of his flesh being put to death enabled sinners to approach God, comes this:

"Whereof I am made a minister... to fulfil the word of God: the mystery which hath been hid from ages and from generations, but now is made manifest to his saints; To whom God would make known what is the riches of the glory of this mystery among the Gentiles; which is Christ in you, the hope of glory, whom we preach..." Colossians 1:25-28 K.J.V.

He strives to help them understand "the mystery of God, and of the Father, and of Christ; In whom are hid all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge. And this I say, lest any man should beguile you with enticing words... Beware lest any man spoil you through philosophy and vain deceit, after the traditions of men, after the rudi-ments of the world, and not after Christ, for in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily." (vss. 2-9)
Note how he said that God kept hidden the depths of the truths about deity and divine purposes, until the appointed time, foreordained from before creation started? Until that time came, it was a divine mystery: known to God but hidden to mankind. Over the centuries hints of what would be revealed were recorded in the Hebrew scriptures, but could not be pooled together until the revelation of the foretold Messiah at his appearing on Earth, life, death, resurrection and return to heaven. Then the apostles understood this mystery of Christ and declared it as the gospel of Christ. It had been revealed to them by God. They did not grasp it through philosophy, or traditions of men!
God reveals his various mysteries, as Jesus said to Peter who suddenly saw and declared that Jesus was the Christ, the Son of the living God (Matthew 16:15-18.) God had revealed that to Peter, and upon that expression of faith as to just who Jesus is, Jesus builds his Church. Unless God reveals his mysteries, they remain mysterious. But when God opens the eyes, ears and understanding of those seeking him, then the mysteries are no longer mysteries, and Christ is seen in his glory - as God incarnate. If the Trinity doctrine was false, then so would be all biblical statements about the full deity of Christ (and the Holy Spirit).
But the question can be put the other way: Is anti-trinitarian belief false? Those who have had the revelation of just who Jesus and the Holy Spirit are, would say, "Yes, it can be falsified by the revelation of God that clears up this mystery of Christ." However, if God chooses not to reveal that particular mystery to them, it will remain obscure, and no amount of philosophising, and following traditions of men, will make them any the wiser.

"It is a bit pointless asking what could any writer of those scriptures have written to falsify it, for that's not going to happen" - well it is the 'point' of this question, as a thought experiment for whether the trinity as defined by trinitarians is falsifiable

The issue of falsifiability is very difficult. What we can argue is to show whether there are good arguments for Trinity (or a particular version of it such as the Roman 'begotten' and separated trinity) throughout the Bible, especially the Hebrew Bible, as you would assume that it's a Christian invention. I'd advise covering a wide range of trinitarian models, that preserves the monotheism or oneness of God. I understand the question to be whether the trinity doctrine comes from silence with respect to the Jewish Bible.
The traditional or Rabbinic Judaism is definitely in contrast with the Trinity, as this sect broke off from the first century Judaism along with Christianity. So, we should not verify Trinity not solely from Rabbinic Judaism, but from first century Judaism, which includes the New Testament. I recommend Jacob Neusner's books for the early first century Judaism.
The mainstream Christian theologians are taught that the Trinity is a surprise revelation in the NT, and not to be found before that; this is because they are completely cut off from the Jewish scripture: see Benjamin Sommer and its various literature.

It is a common belief among religious Jews alike that the doctrine of the Trinity is merely a Christian invention, and before the rise of Christianity, early Jews never thought of or even considered the idea of a multi-personal G-d, and only thought of G-d as being a completely unified single figure (Deuteronomy 6:4). Christians either made up the Trinity to explain how Jesus revealed himself, or they stole it from the pagans. This, however, is simply untrue. And if one took the time to carefully study early Jewish writings you'll find that indeed many Jewish authors struggled with the idea of three powers in the Tanakh who all seemed to be G-d. I will publish more papers exclusively elaborating on the presence of the Trinity in the Tanakh alone, but I'll continue.
דברים ו׳:ד׳
(ד) שְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ יְהֹוָ֥ה ׀ אֶחָֽד׃
Deuteronomy 6:4
(4) Hear, O Israel! יהוה is our God, יהוה alone.
Many ancient Jews and Jewish scholars today recognize the fact that there seemed to be multiple powers in heaven. Jewish Scholar and Theologian Dr. Benjamin D. Sommer has stated in a lecture series on one of his published works The Bodies of God And the World of Ancient Israel that the concept of the Trinity isn't at all foreign to the Near East or in Judaism. In that lecture, he states:
"I'm actually rather uncomfortable with my own conclusion here, but as a Scholar, I got to call 'em as I see 'em..."
he goes on to say,
"...one of the conclusions that I came to, to my shock when I finished this book is that we Jews have no theological objection to the doctrine of the Trinity."

Detailed study reveals the first century Jews would've had no objection to it, as we don't find its controversy in the NT at all. The trinity is absolutely Jewish, not Roman.

Good angle; there has been more Second Temple studies that show the Hebrew way of thinking about God which is in the background of NT thinking (thus first century Judaism) about the precursors of the Trinity.  So this becomes a defense that Trinitarians don't owe the doctrine to Greek philosophy, only borrowing the language.

Reason will prove that the trinity is not an unfalsifiable belief.
If I say "there are three persons in God, I mean three beings, if not three beings, then I should explain my assertion that three persons are not equal to three beings and I should define the words "being" and "person". If I use the words person and being in a different sense, then I must explain the sense I am using these words for. If I cannot explain my different use of the words person and being, then I am using words without ideas and I am postulating an idea that I myself do not understand.
Does a person mean a separate intelligent being. If the answer is yes, then an explanation regarding how could three persons = 1 God is needed. If the is answer no, then the  words person and being are used differently from common sense. Thus, apologists for a multi person god should clarify the meaning of the words person and being.
Examining Deuteronomy 6:4
Echad is a numeral adjective, the ordinary word for the number one. In counting in Hebrew one says , echad (one) sh'nayim (two)..
The word one in the phrase "one God" does not impart plurality to the word God. Even if the compound noun is made up of a number of parts or items, the word 'one' which stands before it is not in any way altered because of its closeness to the compound noun.
How would proponents of one as a "compound one" explain Ecclesiastes 4:9 "two are better than one" Ecclesiastes 4:11 Furthermore, if two lie down together they [e]keep warm, but how can one be warm alone? Ecclesiastes 4:12 And if [f]one can overpower him who is alone, two can resist him.
The use of Genesis 2:24 does not mean that one is really plural. The idea of the plurality cannot be found in the word echad at all.
The Shema declares YHVH's singular uniqueness as Israel's God. There is no evidence in the Hebrew Bible that any generation of Israelites understood the Shema as a reference to a compound unity in God.
If they did, who are the others? There is no record in the bible showing the Israelites knew and identified the other members/parts of this compound/composite God, nor is there such evidence in the New Testament. When the scribe asked Jesus which commandment is the foremost, Jesus quoted the Shema. Mark 12:28-30. The scribe asserted Jesus' answer. It is difficult to believe that Jesus or any person that is postulated to be a part of this composite God, is co-equal and co-eternal with God from the beginning of time, and yet he never appears in the Old Testament.
There is nothing in this account that Jesus reinforced the idea of a compound unity or his place in the Shema
Some may advance the notion that the "one" God applies to both the Father and Jesus but that is false. According to Jesus' own statement, the Father and Jesus count as 2, not 1, as John 8:17-18 show.
John 8:17-18 Literal Standard Version
and also in your law it has been written that the testimony of two men is true; I am [One] who is testifying of Myself, and the Father who sent Me testifies of Me.”
There are numerous verses in clear unaltered scripture language, that show the Father alone is the true God as John 17:3, Mark 12:29-32, Jeremiah 10:10 and Ephesians 4:6 to cite a few.
To say that the "one" God is not really one but two is an attempt to make an apparent polytheism fit into some concept of monotheism.
The word "one" in the Shema in Mark 12:29 is εἷς (heis) not hen as shown in John 17:21-22.
The one/heis (masculine) in Mark 12:29 means mathematical oneness. It does not carry the meaning describing a figurative unity of purpose just as the Greek “one” hen (neuter) does in John 17:21, 22
Examining Isaiah 44:6 ASV we find Thus saith Jehovah, the King of Israel, and his Redeemer, Jehovah of hosts: I am the first, and I am the last; and besides me there is no God.
"his Redeemer" means Israel's Redeemer, YHWH of hosts. There are not two LORDS here where one is the redeemer of the other. Now let us compare scriptures with scriptures.
Revelation 1:17 ASV
And when I saw him, I fell at his feet as one dead. And he laid his right hand upon me, saying, Fear not; I am the first and the last, and the Living one; and I was dead, and behold, I am alive for evermore, and I have the keys of death and of Hades
Notice that Revelation 1:17-18 say that the first and the last was dead. The difference between Jesus being the first and the last compared to YHWH being the first and the last is in the bible. There is no record in the bible that tells us that YHWH was dead because YHWH is immortal. Jesus dying proves he is not YHWH God.
In 1Thessalonians 1:9-10 we find that the true God raised Jesus from the dead. If Jesus was also God he would not have died to begin with. In these verses it was the true God that raised Jesus from the dead, there is no ambuguity about who the true God is in this verse.
The ultimate savior in the bible is God who has sent saviors as recorded in the bible. Nehemiah 9:27, Isaiah 19:20.John 3:16 shows us "For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth on him should not perish, but have eternal life." Note that John 13:16 says that "Verily, verily, I say unto you, a servant is not greater than his lord; neither one that is sent greater than he that sent him" This also reinforces the truth that The Father is greater that Jesus John 14:28, who himself prayed to be save Hebrews 5:7-8
Nehemiah 9:27 ASV
Therefore thou deliveredst them into the hand of their adversaries, who distressed them: and in the time of their trouble, when they cried unto thee, thou heardest from heaven; and according to thy manifold mercies thou gavest them saviours who saved them out of the hand of their adversaries
Isaiah 19:20 ASV
And it shall be for a sign and for a witness unto Jehovah of hosts in the land of Egypt; for they shall cry unto Jehovah because of oppressors, and he will send them a saviour, and a defender, and he will deliver them
Hebrews 5:7 ASV
Who in the days of his flesh, having offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to save him from death, and having been heard for his godly fear

'When one says "there are three persons in God,...' a) where does your quote end and b) who says that? It seems like you are advancing a claim which by definition Trinitarians do not hold and thus cannot be said to falsify Trinitarian doctrine. Furthermore, since the question is about fallibility via Scripture, ipso facto philosophical-like arguments are not directly relevant.

@eques.i googled the definition of the trinity and this is what showed, the Christian Godhead as one God in three persons: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit.. The background of the question also say, "This one being of God is shared by three co-equal, co-eternal persons, the Father, the Son, and the Spirit". Trinitarians generally believe that this doctrine is taught in the New Testament. They also generally believe the trinity is (minimally) compatible with the Hebrew bible, or (maximally) also taught in the Hebrew bible. This is in contrast with traditional Jewish belief in a unitary deity"

I didn't ask where you got your definition of trinity. You said "when one says" which raises the question of who actually said that (not quite the same was what definition of Trinity are you using) and I asked where the quote ended (you omitted a closing quote mark).

This answer attempts to show that the Trinity Doctrine is false. But that's not what the question asked for. It's asking whether it is the type of belief that is theoretically impossible to disprove. E.g. my belief about little green men living on a planet in the JADES-GS-z14-0 galaxy is unfalsifiable.

@RayButterworth. The question is not about e.g. belief about little green men living on a planet in the JADES-GS-z14-0 galaxy is unfalsifiable?  I answered the question"Is the trinity an unfalsifiable belief ".

@AlexBalilo, your answer would be correct if the Catholic Church agreed with your reasoning and dropped their doctrine (or relabeled it as a theological possibility). The answer attempts to do far more than the question asked for. ¶ If I asked whether "Both Trump and Harris were born as biologically female" is a falsifiable belief, the answer would be "Yes, since a DNA test would prove it false if it were false". One could also obtain blood samples, make the test and disprove it, and thereby answer the question, but doing so is far more than was asked for.

@RayButterworth. "your answer would be correct if the Catholic Church agreed with your reasoning and dropped their doctrine (or relabeled it as a theological possibility)" . Is the correctness of an answer dependent on the Catholic church agreeing to my reasoning.instead of agreeing to Christ whose name is the source of Christianity?

@AlexBalilo, I'm not disagreeing with what's given in your answer (I didn't down-vote your answer, nor do I believe the doctrine is biblical); I'm saying that unless the presented proof is so totally convincing that most of the world changes its belief, it doesn't answer the question of falsifiability. The question doesn't ask whether the doctrine is false, it asks whether it's possible that there could be some method of disproving it. ¶ There exist statements (many of which are blatantly false) that cannot be disproved, and the question simply asks whether this doctrine is one of them.
