How do Trinitarian Christians defend the unfalsifiability of the Trinity?
Background:
Christian Trinitarians believe "that there is one eternal being of God – indivisible, infinite. This one being of God is shared by three co-equal, co-eternal persons, the Father, the Son, and the Spirit". Trinitarians generally believe that this doctrine is taught in the New Testament. They also generally believe the trinity is (minimally) compatible with the Hebrew bible, or (maximally) also taught in the Hebrew bible. This is in contrast with traditional Jewish belief in a unitary deity.
The authors of the Hebrew bible make several statements about the oneness of G-d:

Deuteronomy 6:4 - "Hear, O Israel: The Lord our G-d, the Lord is one."


Isaiah 44:6 - "Thus says the Lord, the King of Israel and his Redeemer, the Lord of hosts: 'I am the first and I am the last; besides me there is no god.'"


Deuteronomy 4:35 - "To you it was shown, that you might know that the Lord is G-d; there is no other besides Him."

Unfalsifiable belief?
Under trinitarian hermeneutical approaches, the above verses are not contrary to the trinity because they could be interpreted to refer to the single being of G-d, and not to the trinitarian multiplicity of persons. This is a curious interpretation since concepts of distinction between “person” and “being” only appear in literature which post-date the completion of the Hebrew bible.
Question
If seemingly clear verses attesting to ontological oneness can be used in support of trinitarian doctrine, what could a biblical author have written in the Hebrew bible that would falsify the trinity? Is the trinity only falsifiable with a verse such as "There is only one person of G-d", "G-d is only one being and one person", or even "The trinity as defined by Christian patristic fathers and ecumenical councils in the 4th Century CE is false"?

Jesus came to reveal or fully expound the Father.  It makes sense that what was fully expounded by Jesus was not fully revealed prior to Him.  Good question. +1

Your question assumes the Bible being the only and complete source of truth, apparently. How do you falsify that?

My personal log-book has you asking "Is the trinity an unfalsifiable belief?" on 1 August this year, in Christianity Stack. I answered that question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/102678/is-the-trinity-an-unfalsifiable-belief/102700#102700 which question has been closed as being off-topic. Can you explain how this virtual replication of that previous Q is not also off-topic, please?

If I claim that I had a dream in which the sun and the moon and eleven stars bow down to me, it is impossible to prove that claim to be false. The claim is unfalsifiable. Nevertheless that claim is in scripture. Because it is a matter of personal revelation. Let God be true (if he chooses to speak) and let every man be a liar' (who says that God's truth is false).

@Anne Perhaps it should be voted to close as a duplicate . . . . .

Not the same question. The original closed question was asking an open ended philosophical question, see the moderators suggestion for asking a question suitable for this site: This might be a good question, but it is clearly a philosophical one, not a theological one. If I didn't close it as philosophical, I would have closed it as inviting answers from too many perspectives. If you want to add "How do Trinitarians defend the falsifiability of their belief"....

@avi thank you for taking me seriously on this, I'm not the only authority on what's on topic or what is a duplicate here. My suggestion was to edit your original question, but this is OK.  The problem with my suggestion, on recollection, is that "falsifiability" is a philosophical concept and "trinitarianism" has no teaching authority (outside of the ecumenical councils that defining the Trinity - and nobody ever bothers to reference them here) So you wind up with more philosophical (off topic) answers. Boo -- well Ray did, good job Ray!

"This is a curious interpretation since concepts of distinction between “person” and “being” only appear in literature" It's actually not that curious if you understand that Trinitarian theology is not tritheistic and understand how the 3 Persons are understood in Scripture.

Some statements that could disprove the Christian Trinity:

"God is one being and one person" (your example)
"There are two/fifteen/infinitely many Gods"
"There is one God in three persons: God the Father, God the Mother..."
"This golden calf is your God"

Any of those statements would obviously refute the Trinity. Less trivially, the author of the Koran manages to explicitly refute the doctrine of the Trinity despite the fact that he doesn't seem to understand it himself (let alone knowing modern philosophical and theological terms). While I'm less familiar with the Book of Mormon, as I understand it also refutes the Trinity (and is much closer to "there are infinitely many Gods"). Clearly the Trinity is falsifiable.
So what's actually going on with the Trinity? We have texts that talk about unity (some of which you cited, but also in the New Testament). We have texts that talk about three distinct persons, Father, Son and Holy Spirit (and although it's less explicit, we see hints of those persons already in the Old Testament). The doctrine of the Trinity attempts to reconcile all these texts, and does it well enough to have convinced the vast majority of Christians over millennia (which isn't proof on its own but at least shows that it's a reasonable attempt). It follows that the doctrine of the Trinity doesn't contradict the texts you cite, because it's based on those texts.
Your objection amounts to "your theory is unfalsifiable because you developed it to explain the known data". Well, that's what a theory should do, it's not the same as unfalsifiability. The theory can be falsified by adding new data (as Muslims and Mormons do), rejecting some of the data (as Judaism does), or reinterpreting the data (as non-Trinitarians do).

the author of the Koran manages to explicitly refute the doctrine of the Trinity despite the fact that he doesn't seem to understand it himself - the Quran post-dates the NT and Nicea by centuries. it's at least somewhat likely the author had been exposed to trinitarian theology since it's well known that Christianity was one of the main religions in the pre-islamic Arabian peninsula

rejecting some of the data (as Judaism does) - as non-mormon christians might say in response to Joseph Smith: yes, that's the beauty of a closed canon :)

@AviAvraham the author of the Koran is aware of the Trinity, but he seems to think that it's God, Mary and their kid Jesus. It's this misconception (which understandably shocked him) that he's arguing against, nevertheless his theology is explicit enough to be inconsistent with what Trinitarian Christians actually believe.

@AviAvraham regarding Joseph Smith, I agree. I don't accept Mormon theology because I don't accept some of their data points (not primarily because they don't fit with the Trinity, but also because it's inconsistent with the data I use. Mormons also have to reject some of my data points). The point stands - a conclusion drawn from a given dataset will/should be consistent with that dataset and it's not reasonable to expect it to be disprovable by that same dataset (which is what you're asking for). That's not the same as unfalsifiability.

If I understand correctly, the question being asked is something like this:

Could the Old Testament documents have been written in a way that rejected in advance the Christian doctrine of the Trinity?

I don't mean to be flippant about this rewording of the sentence, because I think that the OP is actually a good question. But the rewording highlights the real issue: The development of trinitarian doctrine is as much historical as it is theological. It arose around the life, death and resurrection of Jesus. The Jesus story, and the claims of Jesus, forced the followers of Jesus (who initially were all committed monotheistic Jews) to revise and expand their understanding of God's nature. If Jesus was God in any meaningful sense, then we have a whole new dimension to consider. The church has wrestled with this enormous subject for the last two thousand years, and most Christians would say that the Trinity is our best synthesis of the data before us.
One important part of the data is the nature of the Messiah, God's anointed servant. It's important to understand that the Christian church has not developed its doctrines out of thin air. Everything ultimately is based on Jesus himself, and his own self-identification as the Son of God. He clearly and consistently claimed to be the Messiah figure predicted by the OT. So the oneness of God is not the only set of texts in the discussion. The OT texts about the Messiah, and how Jesus himself understood them, will also come into play.
Of course each of us must come to our own conclusions on this matter, and hopefully we will be respectful of other views. But for me, the Trinity is a reasoned and reasonable understanding of the God revealed in the whole sweep of the Bible story.

Your restatement is perfectly valid, not flippant at all

Do you mean "expand" where you say "expend"?

Aha, yes. Thanks, and fixed.

"and most Christians would say the Trinity is our best synthesis", etc.  Are you believing you can be a true Christian without believing the Trinity? Or do you mean "most professing Christians", ie most professing themselves to be Christian" (and regularly  attending a place of worship)?

That's a new question, and I can only give my personal thoughts. I find the tag true Christian unhelpful. Eg, I have a Presbyterian background. If I was talking to a JW, arguing over true and false belief won't get us anywhere. I prefer to think in terms of dialogue in which, if we listen well then we both grow in our spiritual life and understanding. That requires humility and grace. As for the Trinity doctrine itself, I'm not hung up on the word. I think it's a good label for all that the Bible says about God, but it is only a label. Scripture is the key source for our understanding.

If I claim that I had a dream in which the sun and the moon and eleven stars bow down to me, it is impossible to prove that claim to be false.
The claim is unfalsifiable.
Nevertheless that claim is in scripture. Because it is a matter of personal revelation.
And, in due course, the dream was realised and known to be a truth.

Unbelievers disbelieve the word of God and disbelieve the revelation that he gives.
But that unbelief does not make truth to be false.
'Let God be true (if he chooses to speak) and let every man be a liar' (who says that God's truth is false).

... yea, let God be true, but every man a liar; as it is written, That thou mightest be justified in thy sayings, and mightest overcome when thou art judged. [Romans 3:4 KJV]

For when people disbelieve the sayings of God and when people sit in judgment of God's word, there is a response to be made. Albeit that there is no way to 'prove' or 'disprove' what God has revealed . . . . . other than by believing His words.

"And, in due course, the dream was realised and known to be a truth." — That's actually not a lot different from my answer, just presented from a different perspective. +1.

The Hebrew Bible would not have in it that which has been written if God existed in one person.  It would have to have said none of the things pointed out in the answer below.  I will come to that, but first...
The authors of the New Testament
The New Testament was mostly written by Jews. All the Apostles were Jews. The Lord Jesus was, of course, Jewish.  The Apostle Paul was a Hebrew of Hebrews, a Pharisee, very zealous for the law, taught under Gamaliel/ Gamliel. This is the Gamaliel who was son of Simon, son of Hillel the Great, founder of one of the main rabbinical schools. Gamaliel was a leader of the Sanhedrin, contributor to the Mishnah.
The books Acts and Luke, written by Luke, a gentile, were added to scripture with Jewish Apostolic approval.  The NT expressly shows the Jewish Apostle Paul approved the Gospel of Luke and referred to it as "scripture" (1 Timothy 5:18 and Luke 10:7).
It is surely both strange and significant that it was Jews, who were taught from their mother's milk to believe there is only one God, who promoted trinitarian theology.
Hints in the OT, aided by NT insight, show that God exists in more than one person
With the aid of the NT it becomes possible to see hints of a Trinitarian Godhead in the OT. So John in his Gospel tells the Word of God was with God and was God, and the Word became flesh.  Knowing this, it becomes possible to see a hint of the Trinity in the opening statement of the Hebrew Bible:

In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. And the earth was without form and void, and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.  And God said.. etc, Genesis 1:1-3.

So God the Father created all things, by the involvement of his Spirit, the Spirit of God, through his Word.  But it takes the eyes of an Apostle to tell us the Word in Genesis 1 was a person of a Triune Godhead.
And then King David prays, "Take not thy holy spirit from me", Psalm 51:11.  Again, this is exactly the experience of those who know they need the help of the Holy Spirit to please the Father.  It is understood with NT eyes.
Verses in the OT that would not appear if God existed in one person
There are verses in the OT which falsify there is only one person in the Godhead. Unfortunately, these verses tend to be translated  in such a way to obscure their meaning in Jewish English translations, such as JPS (Jewish Publication Society) translations.  Multiple Christian versions of verses in English can be compared at biblehub.org.
So, for example, Psalm 2, especially Psalm 2:7 & v12, Isaiah 7:14, Isaiah 9:6, Jeremiah 23:5-6, Ezekiel 44:2-3, and Daniel 7:13-14 all point to more than one person in the Godhead.
Psalm 2 says there will be one who will be son of God.  It cannot mean David or Solomon because unto him will be given the uttermost parts of the earth.  It says:

Blessed are all those who put their trust in him, Psalm 2:12.

Compare this with Psalm 146:3 "Put not your trust in princes" or Psalm 20:7 where exactly the same David writes "Some trust in chariots and some in horses, but we will trust in the name of the LORD our God".
The Jews tried to stone Jesus because he said God was his Father making himself equal with God, John 5:17-18.  But Jesus was only claiming what the Hebrew Bible said would be true of the coming Messiah in Psalm 2, he would be the Son of God. Why did the Jews think he was claiming equality with God when he was only calling God his Father?  It is because the offspring of anything has the same nature as the parent. The Son of God would have the same nature as God the Father.
Isaiah 7:14 says a virgin will bring forth a son and his name will be called "Immanuel" (which means "God with us", Matthew 1:23).  He will be unique in his birth: he will be God with us.
Isaiah 9:6 says "a son is born" and will be called "the Mighty God, the Everlasting Father, the Prince of Peace". Blasphemous names!... unless they are true.
Jeremiah 23:5-6 "I will raise unto David a righteous Branch and a King... and his name shall be called THE LORD OUR RIGHTEOUSNESS".  Again, it is absolute blasphemy... unless this son of David is also God.
Ezekiel 44:1-3 Viewing the gate of the sanctuary that looks towards the east, "then said the LORD to me, This gate shall be shut, it shall not be opened, and no man shall enter in by it; because the LORD, the God of Israel has entered in by it, therefore it shall be shut... the prince... shall enter by the way of the porch of that gate, and shall go out by the way of the same".  Jesus did this on the day he sat on an ass, on a colt, the foal of an ass and rode into Jerusalem, Mark 11:1-11.  He went in that way from the Mount of Olives, and he went back the same way, the same day.  Today, the east gate is shut, it is bricked over, just as the word of the LORD to Ezekiel prophesied.
Daniel 7:13-14 & 27

And I saw in the night visions, and behold, one like the Son of man came with the clouds of heaven, and came unto the Ancient of Days, and they brought him near before him.  And there was given him dominion, and glory, and a kingdom, that all peoples, nations, and languages, should serve him: his dominion is an everlasting dominion, which shall not pass away, and his kingdom that which shall not be destroyed, Daniel 7:13,14.

The key word here is "serve" which is from the Aramaic, "pelach".  It is used only in Daniel, in Daniel 3:12, 14, 17, 18, 28 where it is associated with "worship", or serving a god.  It is also used in Daniel 7:27 where it says:

And the kingdom and dominion, and the greatness of the kingdom under the whole heaven, shall be given to the people of the saints of the Most High, whose kingdom is an everlasting kingdom,  and all dominions shall serve and obey him, Daniel 7:27.

Whose kingdom shall it be?  Daniel 7:13-14 says the Son of Man; Daniel 7:27 says the Most High.  Who will all dominions "serve"?  Daniel 7:14 says the Son of Man, which is blasphemy if he is not also God.  See chapter 3 for how the word is used.
If the Hebrew Bible wanted to point out there was only one person in the Godhead then it is strange it has included these verses.

What the OT writers would have had to have left out is a great angle to answer this question!  +1

@MikeBorden - Thank you Mike.

Except for the short section about "Spirit" (which could be read as a "spirit" force rather than as a person), +1.


If seemingly clear verses attesting to ontological oneness can be used in support of trinitarian doctrine, what could a biblical author have written in the Hebrew bible that would falsify the trinity?

From a historical perspective, this question reverses the order of things, in a somewhat No true Scotsman kind of way.
Even though they do contain many statements about the nature of God, the Hebrew scriptures themselves offer very little evidence that would lead one to deduce the Trinity Doctrine.
The Trinity Doctrine was defined by the Roman Church over a period of many centuries, as described by
Wikipedia:

First Council of Nicaea (325)
In the fourth century, Arianism, as traditionally understood, taught that the Father existed prior to the Son who was not, by nature, God but rather a changeable creature who was granted the dignity of becoming "Son of God".
In 325, the First Council of Nicaea adopted the Nicene Creed which described Christ as "God of God, Light of Light, very God of very God, begotten, not made, being of one substance with the Father", and the "Holy Ghost" as the one by which "was incarnate ... of the Virgin Mary".
("the Word was made flesh and dwelled among us").
About the Father and the Son, the creed used the term homoousios (of one substance) to define the relationship between the Father and the Son.
After more than fifty years of debate, homoousios was recognised as the hallmark of orthodoxy, and was further developed into the formula of "three persons, one being".
The Confession of the First Council of Nicaea, the Nicene Creed, said little about the Holy Spirit.
At the First Council of Nicea (325) all attention was focused on the relationship between the Father and the Son, without making any similar statement about the Holy Spirit.
…


First Council of Constantinople
Later, at the First Council of Constantinople (381), the Nicene Creed would be expanded, known as Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed, by saying that the Holy Spirit is worshiped and glorified together with the Father and the Son (συμπροσκυνούμενον καὶ συνδοξαζόμενον), suggesting that he was also consubstantial with them
…
The doctrine of the divinity and personality of the Holy Spirit was developed by Athanasius in the last decades of his life.
He defended and refined the Nicene formula.
By the end of the 4th century, under the leadership of Basil of Caesarea, Gregory of Nyssa, and Gregory of Nazianzus (the Cappadocian Fathers), the doctrine had reached substantially its current form.


Middle Ages
Gregory of Nazianzus, Gregory of Nyssa, and Basil the Great account for the Trinity saw that the distinctions between the three divine persons were solely in their inner divine relations.
There are not three gods, God is one divine Being in three persons.
Where the Cappadocian Fathers used social analogies to describe the triune nature of God, Augustine of Hippo used psychological analogy.
He believed that if man is created in the image of God, he is created in the image of the Trinity.
Augustine's analogy for the Trinity is the memory, intelligence, and will in the mind of a man.
In short, Christians do not have to think of three persons when they think of God; they may think of one person.
…

What we see in effect is how the doctrine was refined in order for the belief in multiple "gods" to fit with the existing Hebrew scriptures.
Most notable is the statement known as
The Shema (Deuteronomy 6:4–9, 11:13–21, and Numbers 15:37–41):

Its first verse encapsulates the monotheistic essence of Judaism: "Hear, O Israel: YHVH is our God, YHVH is one"

The mystery (incomprehensible to humans except through analogy) of three persons comprising a single being exists because of this clear statement in Hebrew scripture.
So, the answer to the question, "what could a biblical author have written in the Hebrew bible that would falsify the trinity?", is  "nothing".
The Trinity Doctrine was crafted to be compatible with scripture, so had there been any such addition, it too would have been handled during this process.
Note:
This answer is not intended to be anti-Catholic or anti-Trinitarian.
All denominations that want their beliefs to be self-consistent and to be consistent with the Bible must go through a similar process, often with their denominational beliefs affecting how scripture is interpreted.

distinguo some parts of the doctrine of the Trinity could be said to be "developed" over the course of human history - it shouldn't be surprising that it takes time for our philosophy to catch up with reality in the middle ages just as it takes time for our science to catch up with reality in the 19th century.  but other parts make more sense if you'd refer to them as "refined" or "defined" over the ages - to thwart such and such an unforeseen heresy.

@PeterTurner, thanks. The two remaining "developed"s are in the quoted text.

It seems your actual question is more along the lines of "Does there exist a reading of the Old Testament that does not call for a triune God."
I am not prepared to answer that question but I will answer a simpler one. "Does there exist a reading of the Old Testament that does not call for a diune God." I will show God is in at least two persons, and you will find that once having two, it is easier to believe three.
I shall begin with (Gen 6:3; NIV: "My Spirit will not contend with humans forever, for they are mortal ; their days will be a hundred and twenty years.") it is a very odd turn of phrase indeed except for God having more than one person.
And much clearer: NASB: "Then I will come down and speak with you there, and I will take away some of the Spirit who is upon you, and put Him upon them; and they shall bear the burden of the people with you, so that you will not bear it by yourself."
God here is speaking as moving part of a component of Himself.
Joshua 5:13-15 ... and looked, and behold a man was standing opposite him with his sword drawn in his hand, and Joshua went to him and said to him, "Are you for us or for our adversaries?" "No; rather I indeed come now as captain of the host of the Lord." And Joshua fell on his face to the earth, and bowed down to him and said to him "What has my lord to say to his servant?" The captain of the Lord's host said to Joshua, "Remove your sandals from your feet, for the place where you are standing is holy."
Making the mistake of worshiping an angel results invariably in the angel correcting you; but this does not happen here. Rather we get "remove your sandals from your feet"; which is said a few times where God is present. Compare with Exodus 33:20 "He further said, 'You cannot see My face, for mankind shall not see Me and live!'". It's impossible to say these two are the same person of God.
And from the prophets we have:
2 Kings 2:9 "Please let a double portion of your spirit be upon me."
2 Kings 2:13 "Where is the Lord the God of Elijah"
thus the translator is missing a capital S in 2:9. Your spirit has to mean the spirit upon Elijah not the spirit that is the nature of Elijah.
Isaiah 61:1: "The Spirit of the Lord God is upon me, Because the Lord anointed me, To bring the good new to the afflicted, To bind up the brokenhearted, To proclaim liberty to the captives"
"Me" is not the prophet that is Isaiah, for he did not these things nor the things that followed immediately. The Israelites knew how to interpret this the first time, a prophet yet to come. To identify "me" we must scan either forwards or backwards. Scanning backwards results in "I the Lord will hasten it in its time" but the reading is awkward; and perhaps we need to scan forwards. At 61:4 there's a context push, which pops again at 61:7; thus resulting in 61:8 "I, the Lord love justice." In both ways we end up with "I the Lord".
There's no way to make these passages work without at least two persons of God. It looks like three, and I will say there are three, but it's still possible to read two into it with a hostile reading.
But two is enough for today. The fundamental principle is proved; God in more than one person.
Yet you claim it's unfalsifiable because the words to describe it concisely, that splitting of the person and being, post-date the older scriptures. Not so; for if I fed you an exotic new concept and it became necessary to discuss it in detail, new words would appear to describe it. That is the expected result of ordinary mundane things; and I have seen this happen many times over. How much more with divine things where the concepts are hard and the mappings unnatural.
